# Adding a new line into concat() string - Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

Using Angular 4 - the following snippet of code resides in my typescript file.

```
this.tabTitle = "Project Name: " + this.currentProjectRevision.ProjectInformation[0].ProjectName;
```

**this grabs the value of the project name and concatenates it with Project name:**

```
       this.tabTitle = this.tabTitle.concat('/n' + " Quote ID: " + this.quoteInformation.CurrentProjectCustomer.QuoteId);
```

**The above code grabs the first line of codes values and concatenates it with Quote ID: and adds the value of the Quote ID.**

When running this, the output is as follows. Project Name: test /n Quote ID: 0000001

**The actual value stated above gets appended into the following code.**
    Project Name: bvn xbn/n Quote ID: 1000016

I would like to have quote ID start on a new line.
I have tried putting in `<br/>`, `<br>` as well as /n will no success. They are all being added as a string.

Code I have tried so far

```
this.tabTitle = this.tabTitle.concat('<br/>' + " Quote ID: " + this.quoteInformation.CurrentProjectCustomer.QuoteId);

this.tabTitle = this.tabTitle.concat('<br>' + " Quote ID: " + this.quoteInformation.CurrentProjectCustomer.QuoteId);

this.tabTitle = this.tabTitle.concat('/n' + " Quote ID: " + this.quoteInformation.CurrentProjectCustomer.QuoteId);
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show us how you declare `tabTitle` and how you use it in the HTML markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that .concat() follows its own rules. I tested it myself to find out that every line break operator gets ignored.

If you are not bound to using concat(), simply use the '+' operator instead. It proceeds an implicit concatenation.

Try it this way:

```
this.tabTitle += '\n' + " Quote ID: " + this.quoteInformation.CurrentProjectCustomer.QuoteId;
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the ticks to the break tags, I have tried this prior and it was adding it in as a string.

Comment: PS: If this answer helped you, it would be kind if you would mark it as solution.

Comment: Thank you for your help, this helped add the break but wasn't showing the actual line break. Needed to add white-space: pre in order for the css to actually show the break!

Answer (score 5):

You can attach a class to the element with the attribute `white-space: pre;`. This will break it into a new line for you if you're using `/n`.

Comment: Thank you, this was the 2nd part of the answer. Greatly Appreciated.